# SharePoint Error when adding a file

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, permissions

I got wcf server and web server in my environment.

SharePoint is hosted in web server.

When I added a file using this method from the web server , it's OK.

Then design changes come and I added files from wcf server, I hit the error.

```
SPFolder.Files.Add(fileName, memoryStream, true); // Errors here
```

Stack trace:

> The URL 'Template/Template.docx' is invalid.  It may refer to a
>   nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is
>   not in the current Web. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81020030):
>   0x81020030The URL
>   'Template/Template.docx' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent
>   file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the
>   current Web.
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PutFile(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile,
>   Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String
>   bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object
>   varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties,
>   String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64
>   fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String
>   bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId,
>   Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid
>   gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage,
>   String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile,
>   Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String
>   bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object
>   varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties,
>   String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64
>   fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String
>   bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId,
>   Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid
>   gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage,
>   String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)

It's working well when my codes are in web server.
Please help me.

Comment: What is the relationship between 'Template/Template.docx' and the filename in your code ?

Comment: our site is like http://server:port/sites/Name/Template/Template.docx.
Template is a document library and template.docx is the file.
The first part are the sharepoint site name.

Comment: @kevin make sure that you SPFolder belong to the right SPWeb, or try use server relative path for the file